# Google Apps Script not picking up HTML formatting in template

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I'm trying to clean up my code and decided to create a template for the emails rather than having it in the body of the code itself.  A simplified version of my code looks like this:

```
    function emailTest() {

      var templ = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('testSLTMail');

        templ.name = "Fazila";
        templ.student = "Student1";
        templ.oldClass = "classA";
        templ.newClass = "classB";
        templ.sltName = "Fazila";
        templ.changeReason = "testing";

      var message = templ.evaluate().getContent();

      GmailApp.sendEmail('f.yunus@littleilford.org','Test Email', message);
```

And my HTML template looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body> 

    <p> Dear <?= sltName ?> </p>
    <p> <?= name ?> has requested a change to the following student's timetable: </p>
    <p><center><?= student ?>'s timetable from <strong><?= oldClass ?></strong> to <strong><?= newClass ?></strong></center></p>
    <p> The reason for this change request is: </p>
    <p><center><?= changeReason ?></center></p>
    <p> Please confirm this request is authorised below. </p>
    <p> Kind regards </p>
    <p> Fazila </p>

  </body>
</html>
```

However, when I get the email none of the HTML formatting is going through the email I get looks like this:

> ```
> <p> Dear Fazila </p>
> <p> Fazila has requested a change to the following student's timetable: </p>
> <p><center>Student1's timetable from <strong>classA</strong> to <strong>classB</strong></center></p>
> <p> The reason for this change request is: </p>
> <p><center>testing</center></p>
> <p> Please confirm this request is authorised below. </p>
> <p> Kind regards </p>
> <p> Fazila </p>
> ```

I'm obviously missing a step somewhere which tells the apps script to apply the HTML formatting but can't see where.  Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Can you try createHtmlOutputFromFile instead of HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile and tell me what's happening?

Comment: Thanks Kevkeev13.  I'm getting an error message saying Object does not allow properties to be added or changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this Email constructor :

```
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "f.yunus@littleilford.org",
    subject: "test",
    htmlBody: message
});
```

It works!

Answer (score 1):

consider using `htmlBody` option:

```
GmailApp.sendEmail('f.yunus@littleilford.org','Test Email', { htmlBody: message });
```

documented [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however, still no joy the email I get now says "[object Object]".